# Triggering a flip animation in CSS3 with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am attempting to make the boxes in my grid flip over with a button click. With pure CSS3, I can make the animation work with hover. My javascript doesn't work at all. My aim is to trigger this CSS animation by using a button click that calls a function in javascript. Thank you for any help that is offered. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sudoku Grid Attempt</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #sudoku{
        position:relative;
        top:150px;
        left:150px;
        background-color:#666699;
        height:800px;
        width:800px;
        font-family:Lucida Console monospace;
        size:1px;
    }
    .grid{
        position:relative;
        top:65px;
        left:65px;
        width:42px;
        height:42px;
        float:left;
    }
    .square{
        text-align:center;
        height:2.6em;
        width:2.6em;
    }
    .square>.front{
        position:absolute;
        height:2.6em;
        width:2.6em;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:3px;
        border-color:black;
     background-color:#ff6600;
    transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    transition:transform .5s linear 0s;
    }
    .square>.back{
        position:absolute;
        height:2.6em;
        width:2.6em;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:3px;
        border-color:black;
     background-color:#ff0066;
    transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    transition:transform .5s linear 0s;
    }

    /*.square:hover>.front{
        transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
    }*/
    /*.square:hover>.back{
        transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
    }*/
    .frontSide{
        transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
    }
    .backSide{
        transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    .button{
        height:70px;
        width:90px;
        border-radius:70px 70px 70px 70px;
        border-color:#ff3300;
        background-color:#ff3300;
        position:relative;
        top:600px;
        left:-300px;
    }
</style>
<script>
    document.getElementsByClassName("button").addEventListener("click",flipSide,false);
    function flipSide(){
        var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
        var elemF = document.getElementsByClassName("front");
        var elemB = document.getElementsByClassName("back");
        var efs = document.getElementsByClassName("frontSide");
        var ebs = document.getElementsByClassName("backSide");

        elem.elemF += "efs";
        elem.elemB += "ebs";
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="sudoku">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front">1</div>
            <div class="back">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front">3</div>
            <div class="back">4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front">5</div>
            <div class="back">6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front">7</div>
            <div class="back">8</div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front">9</div>
            <div class="back">10</div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front">11</div>
            <div class="back">12</div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front">13</div>
            <div class="back">14</div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front">15</div>
            <div class="back">16</div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front">17</div>
            <div class="back">18</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="grid">
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="grid">
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="grid">
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="grid">
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<button class="button">Solution</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Toggle a class that has the transformation applied and use a `transition` on the element being toggled. Also a live demo would help for something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said this code works in pure CSS, just using `:hover`, I would just use pure Javascript to edit the CSS of the element to do the flip.

The code should look something like this:

```
var k = 0;

function flip() {
    var j = document.getElementById("card");
    k += 180;
    j.style.transform = "rotatey(" + k + "deg)";
    j.style.transitionDuration = "0.5s"

}
```

This is as simple as it gets because it is simply using Javascript to edit the CSS properties of the element. Nothing else.

You could also change `.square:hover > .front` to `#image:active > .front` to achieve the same effect.

Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jwa5jo8/).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you check out jQuery.  jQuery together with jQueryRotate which has a rotate method and an animateTo property that may be what you need.  Here's a simple script to illustrate that when you click on the image it rotates 180 degrees and when you double click on it, it returns to its original position:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title> - demo</title>
      <style type='text/css'>
        #image{ margin:30px 30px; }
      </style>

      <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-latest.js'></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
      <script type='text/javascript'> 
      $(window).load(function(){
      $("#image").rotate({ 
           bind: 
          { 
            click : function() { 
                $(this).rotate({animateTo:180})
            },
          dblclick : function() { 
                $(this).rotate({animateTo:0})
            }
          }
      });
      });  
    </script>
    </head>

   <body>
    <div align="center"><img src="images/wizard.gif" id="image"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/j7gfwfc3/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use getElementsByClassName method you must get specified element index 0 as example below. You will not get that error message after change this part.

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];
    if(button != null)
        button.addEventListener("click",flipSide,false);
```

Instead of this it is better to use getElementById method.